# Using a single store on multiple grids and dropdowns with extjs 4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a store "Contacts". In my application i'm using this in 2 grids and 1 combo box. In Each of these components have varying screen space so i need to define pageSize. What is the best practise for this scenario. Is it better do create 3 different stores. ( I'm using MVC ) . If so, are there naming conventions.

**Edit**

Currently i load the stores in the onLaunch method in my controller

```
 var partsStore = this.getPartsStore();
        partsStore.pageSize = 15;
        partsStore.load({
            scope: this
        });
```

and reference this store in my view

```
Ext.define('Mis.view.JobPartList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.jobpartlist',
    store: 'Parts',
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should create multiple store instances. Not sure what you mean about naming conventions, the store name should stay the same whether you have 1 or multiple instances.

Based on the code you've posted above, it's not going to work, because by adding it to the class definition you're telling it to explicitly share the store.

```
Ext.define('Foo', {
    // ...
    initComponent: function(){
        this.store = new MyStoreType();
        // ...
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Comment: To clarify. You mean to have 1 class for the "Part" store. But to instantiate it 3 times. If you see above i've added some code which shows how i create the store instance.